# When does the soul depart the Body like in 2 Cor. 5:8

Tags: 2-corinthians

2 Corinthians 5:8 states:

> Thus we are full of courage and would prefer to be away from the body and at home with the Lord.

When would the audience of 2 Corinthians have understood the soul to have departed the body?

Comment: [Related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2740/4150), [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13524/4150) and [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8921)

Comment: Extremely relevant: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/22854/6192

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the Bible about souls departing bodies:

- Souls are simply living bodies, both human and animal: (Gen 1:3 — *And to every beast of the earth, and to every fowl of the air, and to every thing that creepeth upon the earth, wherein there is life[soul] …*).
- People don't *have* souls, they *are* souls: (Gen 2:7 — *… and man **became** a living soul*).
- Souls can die: (Eze 18:4 — *…  the soul that sinneth, it shall die*).

Currently we are physical beings with physical bodies:

- At Christ's return, those that are saved will be converted into spirit beings (1Cor 15:52–53 — *… we shall be changed.  For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality*).

2 Corinthians 5:8's "*away from the body*" is simply looking forward to that day when Christians will become immortal spirit beings.

Comment: Very Good answer! +1.

Comment: What do you understand from Jesus saying about him not being a spirt because he has flesh and bones?

Comment: Indeed an excellent answer +1 I do not under why some D.V the scriptures you have quoted,it is obvious that they approach the Bible with preconceived beliefs

Comment: *There is nothing in the Bible about souls departing bodies:*. Genesis 35:18

Comment: @snoopy, The Hebrew word for "soul" is "nehphesh", which means "*that which breathes, the breathing substance or being*".
Notice how Genesis 35:18 is translated into English in other versions:
— NLT: "*Rachel was about to die, but with her last breath …"
— NIV: "*As she breathed her last …*"
— CSB: "*With her last breath …*"
— NET: "*With her dying breath …*"

Comment: @RayButterworth, Yeah I had studied that. The translations you have provided are general translations for the ease of understanding, I had already asked about the correct Hebrew translation of this verse about 10 months ago. "and it happened [that] go out נפשה (her soul/breath/life), for she died". The key is  (נפשה בצאת ) . https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/47404/35803

Answer (score 1):

The soul departing from the body was understood by the audience of 2 Corinthians to mean death.

John Chrysosotom - a Greek - comments:

> See how avoiding painful terms such as "death" and "the end", he
>   employs other terms so as to excite great longing, calling them
>   presence with God; and in passing over the things considered to be
>   sweet - the things of life - he expresses them [instead] in painful
>   terms, calling the life here an absence from the Lord?  He did this so
>   that no one might want to linger among present things, but be wary of
>   them; and that none when about to die might be disquieted.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sup>*Homily X on 2 Corinthians*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jesus' words to the penetent thief on the cross (Luke 23:43) I believe we can safely assume the common understanding was that the soul departs at death.

We can also look at the Greco-Roman history concerning the underworld to see that Paul's Greek listeners would also have understood an immediate transition (Mikalson, Jon D (2010). Ancient Greek Religion. Chichester, West Sussex: Wiley-Blackwell. p. 177.)